# Exactly what does “to love” mean for the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, love

God is Love. Where there is Love, there God is for sure. When we love, we make God present. Where there is no love, there is hatred.

True Love is always of the same nature, whether it is for your mother, your children, or your wife, only in the latter case it has the richness of a sexual expression, which is not necessary but it has it in case you want to use it as a means of expression, and it is very natural and proper to use it.

Love of friends or of all mankind is usually of lesser intensity, except in very religious persons, whose love of neighbor, by command of Jesus Christ, is as strong as the love of their own or of themselves.

Love of homeland, according to persons and times, can be as strong as love for a mother, and therefore one dies very often in history for this cause, and this love also constitutes a duty for religious persons. And then there is the Love of Love, that is, the Love of God, which again for religious people comes first in importance, above all else.

Love is a bond, that is, it is not a feeling. You love your mother, for example, and that remains even if at a certain moment you are angry with her. You love her because you are her child, period. Well, love for your wife is of the same nature: if you notice that you no longer feel the same for her, it does not mean that the love has died, but that you do not feel it.

You do not have to separate but continue to be by her side, waiting to feel it again or assuming that you will no longer feel it as before, but you are by her side because she is your wife and your family, and you are not going to destroy your family and yourself because your heart does not feel it.

That is love, bond, not feeling, and the bond can never be broken, while the feeling can vary throughout life.

That is why true Love always forgives, although it also firmly tells the truths to the face to help the other to be better, but then forgives him and accompanies him with patience, bearing his defects.

Love, therefore, never dies, for although living beings do die, a spirit cannot die.

**BUT**, exactly, what does ***“to love”*** mean for the Catholic Church?

Commitment, sacrifice, love and protection?

Comment: this question, good as it is, is a little broad.  You're likely to get something between a vapid quip and a regurgitation of Pope John Paul II's Love and Responsibility.  I think the first thing to narrow down is which love are you talking about (my guess would be _caritas_ or disinterested love)

Comment: @PeterTurner I think I can answer this one quite specifically, deploying resources from Aquinas 101 and C.S. Lewis's Four Loves book, which should provide a unifying 1-3 concepts that ties all different forms of love together, but I'm busy now, probably next week.

Comment: Until I write a proper answer, please check out Fr. Pine's short treatment of Love as Passion in the short video [Lesson 51: The Passions in General](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/passions-of-the-soul) specifically starting at 4:28 where he talks about love (as passion) and how the dynamic of love links to God.  Then [Lesson 64: Charity](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/charity) talks about how the theological virtue of Charity perfects this passion.  The structure of C.S. Lewis's "The Four Loves" is similar.

Comment: What exactly does it mean in English?…

Comment: @PeterTurner Is it that there are different types of love?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Would be awesome read you, like always! Good luck in your things!

Comment: @Geremia a fine question beyond the scope of this site. 

Answer (score 1):

Most Catholic theologians would agree that to love is to "will the good of another." So, if you will what is good for someone, you are loving them. If someone needs food and you give it to them because you want what's good for them, that is love. If someone is sinning and you intervene to show them the error of their ways because you want them to go for heaven, you are willing their good. That is loving them.

When we talk about God as Love, this is what we mean. We are talking about willing what is good. To say that God willed creation into existence is the same as to say He loved it into existence. He loved what was not, and made it so, because it is better to be than not to be.

English speakers use love in a plethora of ways. We mean something different when we say we love our family vs our spouse vs our dog vs our country vs our job. But when the Church is talking about loving, she means willing the good of others.